# Does anybody know how to hide the amount of hours you have played a game on xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

How do I stop my Xbox 360 tracking my gametime, in Battlefield 3?

Comment: i doubt that its possible

Comment: I'm nearly positive that's impossible.
Several other applications actually tract time played.  The game itself, Battlelog, and BF3Stats.com.  It's a field associated with your player that DICE uses for tracking, but also publishes it for external tracking.

Answer (score -1):

that´s not possible at all, the game tracks you online and that data goes to EA´s server. You don´t have acess to their data so you can´t delete it.